# (Xn) sequence of random variable there exist a sequence of constants (An) such that Xn/An->0 a.s

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

> show that for any sequence (Xn) of random variables there exist a sequence of constants (An) such that Xn/An converge to 0 a.s

> My attempt

Let X1, X2, X3,... be Independent with mean 0 and Sn=X1+X2+X3+...+Xn , and also assume a sequence
(an)->♾️ and I trying to use Borel cantelli lemma  but I am not able to Complitely solve this question **please help me**

Thank you

Comment: Choose $A_n$ such that $P(|X_n| >A_n/n)<\frac1 {2^{n}}$ and apply Borel-Cantelli.

Comment: Please write complete solution

Comment: This question has  been answred many times on this site.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting. That may help you to find similar questions answered here.